# choose unique random numbers with specific range

Tags: java, random, probability

my problem is I want my program to make four unique random choices in range of numbers between 0 to 3 I tried to do it in random class but I could not, , if you could help by code it will be great,my program will be something like this to make it clear

```
my range

0 1 2 3  randomly chosen number 3

0 1 2    randomly chosen number 1

0 2      randomly chosen number 2

0        it will choose 0 and then the program closes
```

Comment: Please show the code you wrote.

Comment: You're selecting 4 random numbers (without replacement) from a set of 4 numbers?  What are you really trying to achieve?  Are you just trying to randomise the sequence of the numbers 0-3?

Comment: it's actually a function not a whole program, not trying to randomise i want if i choose an element from an array it doesn't choose it again

Answer (score 8):

You're effectively looking for a random permutation of the integers from `0` to `n-1`.

You could put the numbers from `0` to `n-1` into an `ArrayList`, then call [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) on that list, and then fetch the numbers from the list one by one:

```
    final int n = 4;
    final ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(n); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(arr);
    for (Integer val : arr) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
```

`Collectons.shuffle()` guarantees that all permutations occur with equal likelihood.

If you wish, you could encapsulate this into an [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html):

```
    public class ChooseUnique implements Iterable<Integer> {

        private final ArrayList<Integer> arr;

        public ChooseUnique(int n) {
            arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr.add(i);
            }
            Collections.shuffle(arr);
        }

        public Iterator iterator() {
            return arr.iterator();
        }
    }
```

When you iterate over an instance of this class, it produces a random permutation:

```
    ChooseUnique ch = new ChooseUnique(4);
    for (int val : ch) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
```

On one particular run, this printed out `1 0 2 3`.

Comment: thank you but this doesn't solve it , shuffle don't ensure unique no

Comment: @ray: Actually, it does. Every number occurs in the final list exactly once. Have you tried running the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could fill an (if you don't need too many numbers) `ArrayList<Integer>` with numbers ranging from 0 - 3. Then you get a random index using `Random.nextInt(list.size())`, get the number from the list and `removeAt` the entry at your index.

Comment: there isn't removeAt method in ArrayList, could pls put some code, i've trying for 2 hours to solve it thanks

Comment: Sorry, it's just called `remove(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your range in sometype of array, then just use a random over the length of the array.

For example if you have an int array called `range`. Then you could use:

```
java.utils.Random randomGenarator = new java.utils.Random();
return range[randomGenarator.nextInt(range.length)];
```